# No access to properties from derived class in razor pages

Tags: entity-framework, razor-pages

Why can't i access property from the subclass? I hope i don't have to create separate variables for every of subclass in order to get data from.

My base class:

```
 public class BookModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Tittle { get; set; }
    public string? Author { get; set; }
    public string? Genre { get; set; }
    public int? Pages { get; set; }
    public bool Lent { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LoanDateTimeStart { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? LoanDateTimeEnd { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public UserModel? User { get; set; }

}
```

Derived class:

```
 public class MovieModel : BookModel
{
    [Column("Length(min)")]
    public int? Length { get; set; }
    public string? Director { get; set; }

}
```

Then my htmlcs:

```
  public class SearchModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public string? SearchKey { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<BookModel> AllObjects { get; set; } = new List<BookModel>();
    public ApiManager? apiManager { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKey))
        {
            apiManager = new();
            AllObjects = await apiManager.GetAllObjects();
           // return all or null

        }
        else
        {
            // var allObjects = await apiManager.ReturnAllObjects();
            // Objects = allObjects.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(SearchKey, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

and finally how it looks like in cshtml page with [red underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzFkp.png)

Comment: The model only knows about `BookModel`, not `MovieModel`, why would it know that the objects have been inherited?

Comment: `public List<MovieModel> AllObjects { get; set; } = new List<MovieModel>();`

Comment: For movies, unbox them in your view with `var movie = (MovieModel) obj;` Then use `movie.Length`.

Comment: @DavidG
Yes it makes sense. I was thinking base class contains every properties from subclasses but i was wrong.

Comment: @MikeBrind
Seem like it could be a solution however i need also other subclasses data in my view. I didn't included them in my message in order to make things simple but i do have other subclasses.

Comment: @mxmissile
I tried that however i am getting this error: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'LibraryApp.Models.BookModel' to type 'LibraryApp.Models.MovieModel'.

Comment: So AllObjects are not all `MovieModel`?

Comment: nope, i have also EbookModel subclass